# Method of communication in Distributed Systems

Tags: distributed-systems, message-passing, shared-memory

Why the method of communication used in DS is message passing and not shared memory ?

Comment: How do you propose to share memory between nodes in a distributed system?

Comment: @tangrs For example , we can select one main node to have this shared memory and the other nodes can communicate via this shared memory ?

Comment: How would the other nodes access this shared memory?

Answer (score 1):

Because in a distributed system, nodes do not have access to shared memory that is shared between all nodes.  Shared memory is only typically feasible when the nodes are on a common memory bus, e.g., for multiple core within a parallel processing machine.